# Iran visa after having visited Israel

Tags: visas, passports, israel, iran, italian-citizens

I'm considering going to Iran this summer so I'm reading the [wikivoyage article](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Iran) which states

> Entry will be refused to citizens of Israel and foreign travellers
>   with any evidence of visiting Israel — not just Israeli entry stamps,
>   but Egyptian/Jordanian neighbouring land borders with Israel — except
>   that if you had an Israeli visa that expired more than a year before
>   you apply for an Iranian visa, you may be allowed entry into Iran

I've an Italian passport and visited Israel in 2008 when my passport was stamped (even though I asked for a paper stamp). Judging from the above quote it seems I'm fine because the Israeli visa expired more or less six years ago. The official Italy-Iran consulate's site doesn't tell much about this issue nor I could find any other source which mentions this option. For example, [Uppersia tour operator](https://www.uppersia.com/Iran-travel-QA/can-a-person-enter-iran-with-an-israeli-immigration-stamp-in-heir-passport.html) (one of the first Google search result) states

> Due to the rules dominating over Iran, entry to Iran will be refused
>   for citizens of Israel and travelers with any evidence of visiting
>   Israel.

without mentioning the expired-more-than-a-year-ago escamotage.

Does wikivoyage state the truth or better I buy another passport?

Comment: You should probably contact your local Iranian consulate and ask them.

Comment: I will but usually travel.SE provides better answers than the consulate one :D

Comment: Did you get to visit the country in the end? What happened?

Answer (score 11):

This is not true as a general rule of Iran. This seems more like propaganda against Iran.

Anyone wanting to travel to Iran should first apply for a visa in any Iranian embassy. If the applicant has visited Israel before, there will not be a default reason for refusing - but it depends on the case. Each case will be checked individually and if there is any problem, it will be refused. Otherwise the visa will be issued.

Anyway, no official rule exists about this and everything depends per case.

**Reference:**

By phone calling to this center: http://www.iranianshouse.ir/

---

*The reasons for refusal can be, for example, relating to spying or terrorism like terrorizing different Iranian scientists like this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majid_Shahriari*

Answer (score 7):

I can't really answer your question, but if I were you I would definitely get a new passport before applying for the visa. These kind of things are often handled by the local officer and no-one will give you any guarantees that you will be admitted to the country even if you have a valid visa and a letter from the embassy.

Comment: I want to add that Germany and presumably Italy as well considers this kind of situation a valid reason to hand out a new passport. So if anyone asks why you want a new passport although the old one is still valid Israel/ Iran travel is a valid reason.

Answer (score 6):

According to [6. Passport requirements](http://www.magiccarpettravel.co.uk/iran-visa/) at [Magic Carpet Travel](http://www.magiccarpettravel.co.uk/).

> If you have Israeli or USA visa stamps in your passport, contrary to
>   popular  belief, this will not jeopardize your application for an
>   Iranian visa

---

### Update

I did get a VISA granted.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents -

***Officialy*** This is not a problem for visiting Iran nor for getting a visa.

Strangely enough - AFAIK ***Officialy*** there is no problem to enter Iran with an Israeli passport.

**Unofficialy** ( and my own opinion ) - better not to have any of this evidence and just get a new passport - not only for the sake of the visa application but for the whole journey where you will usually need to present your passport in multiple locations and can never predict thee reations.